# Does the list returned from Arrays.asList maintain the same order as the original array collection?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I've got an ArrayList that I'm iterating over several times, and it looks like it isn't maintaining the order of iteration. I looked deeper, and it appears that the custom iterator tag that was written for this iteration (by someone else) is first taking the passed in ArrayList and using Arrays.asList to bridge it to an Object[] collection before iterating. Is the order of iteration being lost? Is that expected with Arrays.asList?

EDIT:

Here is the what the operation does with the original collection passed into the iterator tag:

```
if(collection.getClass().isArray()) {
    iterator = Arrays.asList((Object[]) collection).iterator();
} else if(collection instanceof Collection) {
    iterator = ((Collection) collection).iterator();
} else if(collection instanceof Iterator) {
    iterator = (Iterator) collection;
} else if(collection instanceof Map) {
    iterator = ((Map) collection).entrySet().iterator();
}
```

Comment: Was the ordering lost in your case?

Comment: It seems that way, but I'm trying to pinpoint why, or if it is an issue with how I constructed the UI, and not the iteration itself. The custom iterator I'm working with is "difficult" to say the least.

Comment: you mix something up, the method checks if collection is an array and if it is wraps it in a list, if collection is an Arraylist as you claim then it only returns the iterator see the instanceof Collection part.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The List is still backed by the original array, so items should appear in the same order as they do in the array.

Also, note that asList is a generic method, so `Arrays.asList(T[])` will return a `List<T>`.

As for the other direction, `List`'s `toArray`

> Returns an array containing all of the
>   elements in this list in proper
>   sequence (from first to last element).

There are two toArray methods.  The first returns an `Object[]`, the second take an array as its argument and returns as array of the same type.

Something like this is not uncommon, using an array of String as an example:

```
String[] y = x.toArray(new String[0]);
```

(This example is taken from the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) for `List<E>`)

Comment: Even though the objects are backed, the iteration is now through Object[], which is why I thought it might lose the order of iteration.

Comment: @hal10001: Wait... wouldn't that be using `List`'s `toArray()` rather than `Arrays.asList()`?

Comment: I added some of the code to better assess what is happening with the original collection.

Comment: @hal: Since when are items in an array not ordered? They're ordered by index, right? Aren't you somewhere confusing with hashmaps/hashsets/hashtables?

Comment: @BalusC: The original ArrayList is ordered, but I'm trying to figure out if the backed List is ordered or not in this case.

Comment: @Bemrose, a more efficient way for the last example that you gave is: `String[] y = x.toArray(new String[x.size()]);`

Comment: @hal10001: I think you're confused... if an `ArrayList` is provided to the code you posted as `collection`, its `Iterator` will be used directly since it's an instance of `Collection`. If an array is provided to that code, `Arrays.asList` will be used to bridge that array to a `List`, not the other way around.

Comment: @peakit: Probably, but I decided to be lazy and steal the example from the JavaDoc instead of write my own.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly where the iteration is being thrown off is if `collection` is a Map

```
 else if(collection instanceof Map) {
    iterator = ((Map) collection).entrySet().iterator();
}
```

If `collection` is specifically a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), the order of the collection's elements are indeed tossed out the window.

If `collection` is a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), it **should** maintain the order of the collection, based on sorting. However, if you make a TreeMap out of an array of [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) objects, you **shouldn't** expect the array and the TreeMap to have the same order, since the TreeMap will sort the contents of the array.

And you could also be getting some other `Collection` which will muck around with order like [HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), etc.

However, if `collection` is never a Map and always an Array, `Arrays.asList` **should** maintain the order. My best guess is that your issues lies either outside of your code snippet, or in one of the cases besides where you passed an Array.

Comment: I just realized that... if I have a TreeMap, and then it is cast to a Map, that iteration order is lost isn't it?

Comment: @hal10001 if it's a TreeMap, the iteration order shouldn't be lost (just because you treat a TreeMap like a Map doesn't mean it loses its qualities as a TreeMap). If that's the case, I'm a little confused now :-p

Comment: @hal10001: Casting never changes the behavior or structure of an object, it just changes the type you're referring to that object as.

Comment: @hal10001 like ColinD said. Just because I call a Grizzly Bear a 'Bear,' doesn't mean it isn't a Grizzly Bear anymore. Just as far as everyone nearby knows, it's a Bear.

Comment: Thanks ColinD for the straightforward clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more generic replacing `Collection` with `Iterable`.

```
} else if(collection instanceof Iterable) {
    iterator = ((Iterable) collection).iterator()
```

Note: primitive arrays like `int[].class.isArray() == true`, but they cannot be cast with `Object[]`

Comment: I'm working with an API that was developed years ago by someone else in a JAR file, so unfortunately I can't change the iterator tag implementation.